# Mixing PHP and HTML code

Tags: php

I cannot figure this out after looking and googling for hours.

```
<?php           
foreach ($myResults as $rowNumber => $myResult) {
if ($rowNumber<$numberOfResults/2) {
print "<h2>";
print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;       
print "</h2>";
}?>
  html code here

<?php 
 elseif ($rowNumber>$numberOfResults/2) {   
 print "<h2>";
 print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;      
 print "</h2>";
}
} ?>
```

Comment: What can't you figure out? What is your question?

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. What are you trying to achieve? Where was the error? ANd I would reccomand using echo rather then print.

Comment: Sorry. First time posting. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the `html code here` block to only display if the first if test is `TRUE`.  If that is the case, move the trailing `}` before the html block to after.

```
<?php           
  foreach ($myResults as $rowNumber => $myResult) {
    if ($rowNumber<$numberOfResults/2) {
      print "<h2>";
      print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;       
      print "</h2>";
?>
  html code here
<?php 
     }elseif ($rowNumber>$numberOfResults/2) {   
       print "<h2>";
       print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;      
       print "</h2>";
     }
  } 
?>
```

if you want the `html code here` to go after both move it out of the middle of the if statement.

```
<?php           
  foreach ($myResults as $rowNumber => $myResult) {
    if ($rowNumber<$numberOfResults/2) {
      print "<h2>";
      print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;       
      print "</h2>";
    }elseif ($rowNumber>$numberOfResults/2) {   
      print "<h2>";
      print render($myResult->field_field_item_category[0]['rendered']['#title']) ;      
      print "</h2>";
    }
  } 
?>
  html code here
```

Also, **indent**.  It makes the source of errors like this more obvious.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. Why did what I did not work? I did not think ending and starting php was a problem?

Comment: I am tryig to create 2 separate divs that float to make columns.

Comment: Ah, that is because you are printint one result then the other.  I will update.  Also include the 2 floating div thing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to echo HTML code between a the end of your `IF` statement and the start of your `ELSEIF`

```
if(something)
{
  // conditional code here
}

// do not put code here

elseif (somethingelse)
{
  // conditional code here
}
```

Comment: OK. But I thought if I exited the php I could inject a new div via HTML and then open the PHP again?

Comment: Yes you can but the places you've decided to do that is invalid and makes no programmatic sense :) you an do this within the braces `{` and `}` of your conditionals

Comment: nope, the php happens, then the html happens, then it loops,  the php happens, then the html happens, then it loops,  the php happens, then the html happens, then it loops,  the php happens, then the html happens, then it loops, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The sections between `<?php` and `?>` are interpreted as PHP code. The rest is plain HTML code.

There can not be anythig between `if() { }` and `elseif() { }` in PHP (and any language), neither HTML code.

Change `elseif` to `if` and it will work.